# Address of a node in linked list changes automatically in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am learning pointers in `c` and wrote a program which inserts elements into linked list and prints them in the end.

```
// this is exercise 2 in chapter 11 on pointers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node * next;
}node;

/**
Insert into linked list
**/

bool insert(node * list, int n);

void printList(node *startNode);

int main(void)
{
    node n1,n2;
    n1.value  = 0;
    n2.value  = 1;
    n1.next   = &n2;
    n2.next   = NULL;
    // insert 2 into list
    insert(&n1, 2);
    // print the updated list
    printList(&n1);
    printf("Program Executed Successfully \n");
    return 0;
 }

bool  insert(node * list, int n)
{
  while(list->next != NULL)
  {
    if (list->value < n)
    {
      list = list->next;
    }
    else
    {
      node tempNode;
      tempNode.value = n;
      tempNode.next = list->next;
      list->next = &tempNode ;
      return true;
    }
  }
  node tempNode;
  tempNode.value = n;
  tempNode.next = list->next;
  list->next = &tempNode ;

  return false;
}

void printList(node * startNode)
{
  while(startNode->next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%i\n", startNode->value);
    startNode = startNode->next;
  }
}
```

Insertion seems to be fine. I have initially two nodes and then I added one more with a value of `2` but when I print, it just prints the first two elements correctly.

I used GDB debugger and tried to trace where the problem occurs, i saw that when it has printer first and second node, the address of the third node has automatically changed to

> 0x7ffff7dea560 <_dl_fini>

before at the start of the print function it was

> 0x7ffffe018

and the output of the complete program is

> 0
>
> 1
>
> -777224576
>
> -443987883
>
> Segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` function just looks wrong, but the worst offenders are these lines from the function:

```
else
{
    node tempNode;
    ...
    list->next = &tempNode ;
}
```

Here you declare a ***local*** variable `tempNode, and save a pointer to it in the list. The variable will go out of scope and cease to exist once the closing curly brace is reached, leaving you with a stray pointer. Attempting to dereference that stray pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

A little further down you do the same mistake again, saving a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: for `stray pointers`. I did not know that before. thanks for new concept.

Comment: I don't want to pass a new node everytime from outside of the function to add a new node. I just want to tell the value of the node to be inserted. Can you give me an idea? `malloc` would work?

Comment: @GulluButt Using `malloc` would definitely work, but then you can't create parts of your list on the stack in the `main` function like you currently do, you have to create *all* nodes dynamically. Also don't forget to `free` the nodes once you're done with them.